# Warning in an Anchor Tag in a JSP File

Tags: java, jsp

I am able see the warning in a jsp file for the anchor tag.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Bills Added</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Bills Added</h1>

<p>You have added a new bill at</p>


<c:url var="mainUrl" value="/bills/add" />
<p>Return to <a href="${mainUrl}">Main List</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

In the line `<p>Return to <a href="${mainUrl}">Main List</a></p>` its showing a warning:

```
WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/${mainUrl} not found.
```

I can understand about the `c:url` tag but in the `href` with the place holder `${mainUrl}`, then its showing warning in all the files which I have placed like this format. Please neeed suggestion to fix this or why am getting this?

Comment: @Richard - Thanks for editing and make it more clear

Comment: if you don't want to see warnings, then disable html validation.

Comment: @Rembo - ok. I am suspecting, this warning has any link for not picking the jsp file. so thought to fix it more than removing this.